# Ambiguous method call using Project Lombok

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have the following code:

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
@Builder
public class NameParserResponse {
    private boolean match;
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NameParserResponse nameParserResponse = NameParserResponse.builder().build();
        nameParserResponse.isMatch();
    }
}
```

When trying to reference isMatch(), I get:

```
Ambiguous method call. Both

isMatch () in Response and
isMatch () in Response match
```

[image]

I have also tried removing the `@Builder` annotation, but this doesn't help.

Comment: Show more code please.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding project and/or invalidate Intellij caches? 
Also you're wokring with intellij alone or in pair with some building tool like maven or gradle?

Comment: I am using Maven with Intellij, and I have tried running the cleanup command, and have did the invalidate caches / restart option. I actually just created a brand new project with the code above, and still the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried removing `@Getter` and making a getter yourself called `isMatch()`? Does the problem persist?

Comment: After removing the `@Getter`, there is no error. Also, I am using Lombok `1.16.20` and the latest version of Intellij/Lombok plugins.

Comment: try Kotlin if you feel like needing Lombok for Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like I had the `Hrisey` Intellij plugin installed in addition to the `Project Lombok` plugin. I must have accidentally installed this when I was looking for the `Project Lombok` plugin.

After disabling this plugin, the issue was no longer present.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ has a refactoring to "de-Lombok" the code, which will expand the Lombok magic out into the more lengthy code it auto-generates behind the scenes. When I've encountered oddities like this before, looking at the actual produced code, instead of just guessing about it, has helped make the problem clearer. YMMV.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks - I have checked the source code. There are no ambiguous "isMatch" methods, not even two methods named this. The weird thing is it is just on my work computer, at home this issue does not occur. I am trying to check the differences between the two environments. I am up to date on Intellij/Lombok.

Comment: One difference that I just thought about would be that I am using the Ultimate edition of Intellij at home, but the Community Edition at work. Hmm...