# Ambiguous method call using Project Lombok with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I am facing the same issue with this question: [Ambiguous method call using Project Lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162233/ambiguous-method-call-using-project-lombok)

However, I do not have Hrisey installed.

Show far I have tried the following:

- Installed Lombok plugin on IntelliJ IDEA
- Enabled Lombok plugin for this project
- Enabled annotation processing under Compiler settings
- Updated IntelliJ to July 11th version.

Finally, restarted, uninstalled the plugin, tried everything again, and restarted again.

The issue still persists.

Edit:Upgraded to latest (20th Sept) version and still facing the issue.

Comment: Despite you have the same problem posted in that other question, you should post your code (or is it 100% identical to the one in the linked question?).

Comment: Tried the same code as well, no difference made

Answer (score 1):

ran into the same issue... turns out I had both
`@Data` and `@Value` annotated classes (you really need only one). Removed `@Value` and the warning went away.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug. You could [report it](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/new) in the IntelliJ IDEA [Lombok Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok-plugin)